# Get list of surrounding buildings based on coordinates from open database on Web

Tags: php, service, geolocation, location-aware

I would like to get a list of well-known buildings(museums, castles etc..) within X meters radius of the current coordinate. I would like to query them in PHP.

Do you know any such database that can be queried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/):

> The GeoNames geographical database
> covers all countries and contains over
> eight million placenames that are
> available for download free of charge.

Comment: Thanks. After I checked out, worth to know, that has very limited records for Europe and Eastern-Europe most specially for Hungary an Romania, which are my major target for this project.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Places](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) should do well. As far as I know, open developer beta has already been released (and since it's open I'm quite sure it's stable enough).

Comment: Do you know much more about it? Can return localized names, eg: Europos Parlamentas for European Parliament?

Comment: I'm afraid not, documentation does not mention any argument for localized result. Might try using http://maps.google.es/ instead, yet it most probably api just doesn't care.